# If statement to match String in bs4 output

Tags: python, if-statement, beautifulsoup

Need some assistance. I have a function where I use the find_all function on my bs object to print some specific html. my goal here is to eventually match the productName and color together so I can go to the correct link but I am having some trouble picking out the correct word. Here is my code and I get no output when I run this.

```
def getPremeProduct() -> str:
session = requests.Session()
base = "http://www.supremenewyork.com"
r = session.get('http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/accessories')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
keyword = input('Input your keyword: ')
color = str(input('input your color: '))
productColor = soup.findAll('p', text=re.compile(r'\bChecker\b'))
productName = soup.findAll('a', text=re.compile(r'\bTees\b'))

if "Checker" in productName:
    print(productName)

### Here are the outputs for productName
#<a class="name-link" href="/shop/accessories/s4o3fjcg0/eq35gubw7">Supreme®/Hanes® Checker Tagless Tees (2 Pack)</a>
#<a class="name-link" href="/shop/accessories/hz7wj2ui4/jx7qm1hsc">Supreme®/Hanes® Tagless Tees (3 Pack)</a>
#<a class="name-link" href="/shop/accessories/hz7wj2ui4/yks6zay73">Supreme®/Hanes® Tagless Tees (3 Pack)</a>
```

Anyone have any ideas why my if statement isn't printing out just the one result that has "Checker" included? Thanks

Comment: Because you literally ask your computer to print the whole object with `print(productName)`.

Comment: @ForceBru Yeaaaaaa I just figured that out. Need to make it a string. whoops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with your code:

1. You should indent your code when defining a function. I.e. code under `def` should be indented wrt. the `def` keyword.
2. why use `input` if you are not using it later?
3. [pep 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id45) specifies a naming convention for variable names. It might be a good idea to follow that. To be more specific:

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by
>   underscores as necessary to improve readability.
>
> Variable names follow the same convention as function names.

Going back to your problem, the most straight forward way of doing what you want is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def get_product():
    session = requests.Session()
    r = session.get('http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/accessories')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    product_names = soup.findAll('a', text=re.compile(r'\bTees\b'))
    product_names = [link.get_text() for link in product_names]
    return product_names

products = get_product()
for item in products:
    if 'Checker' in item:
        print('yas gurl!')
```

Comment: The code is indented. Must have not shown on here. I plan on using input later. just haven't got there yet. I would like to thank you for the for loop tho. that helped with another trouble I was having. This is my first "big" programming project so sure to be many questions. Thank you

Comment: @BallaBaby sure! If my answer is helpful please accept it.

Comment: I am unable to upvote it since I am still a new user. Not seeing an "accept" button here

Comment: got it. Thanks again! Everything is a learning experience. Small steps

Comment: @BallaBaby thanks! :) one more thing: I'm not sure if you really need type annotations in your code right now, maybe rethink using them?

Comment: You are probably correct. I started this function thinking I would end up with a string but I am actually not sure what the end result of my function will be yet. Was just trying to keep up with correct py practices

Answer (score 0):

soup.findAll finds mutiple elements. You therefore need to iterate them:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getPremeProduct() -> str:
    session = requests.Session()
    base = "http://www.supremenewyork.com"
    r = session.get('http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/accessories')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    keyword = input('Input your keyword: ')
    color = str(input('input your color: '))
    productColor = soup.findAll('p', text=re.compile(r'\bChecker\b'))
    productNames = soup.findAll('a', text=re.compile(r'\bTees\b'))

for product_name in ProductNames:
    product_name = str(product_name)
    if "Checker" in product_name:
        print(product_name)
```